# Having issue with new code for Android

Tags: android

and thanks in advance for any help.  I have been dabbling in this code for a little bit, and most of the errors I have ran across I have been able to fix.  This one has me boggled though.  I have read through a bunch of these other posts talking about using the android dev code for your first app, but I am not sharing the same issues.  As in no spelling errors, no missing code, afaict. Anyway on to the code at hand.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/button_send" 
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.my.first.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity<View> extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/**Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
    // Do something in response to button
}
}

DisplayMessageActivity.java

package com.example.my.first.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra (MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
}


}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.my.first.app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.my.first.app.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Now I am really hoping that this is simply a doh moment.  I am getting no errors in eclipse, but when I run LINT it picks up this error:

```
Corresponding method handler 'public void sendMessage(android.view.View)' not found
```

Again thank you for any help in this matter.

Comment: Why do you have MainActivity<View> instead of MainActivity?

Comment: Not to sure why that was there, taken care of, and it works well.  Thanks much :D

Comment: @Luke Please post this as an answer so that it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `MainActivity<View>` with `MainActivity`.